# pdf thumbnails like in ibooks on the ipad or iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i need to create a pdf reader with an overview page showing thumbnails of the pdf. like with the pdfs in ibooks.
what would be the best approach for that? 
i am thinking about using a uiscrollview and placing uiviews with tiledlayers for pdf rendering? how can i best determine which view is visible and recycle them accordingly?

thanks

joerg

Answer (score 0):

Apple has sample code to get a PDF thumbnail on their developer site. I believe it is in the [Quartz2d Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/index.html) (unfortunately the site is down for me at the minute so I can't confirm).